# Merge Array based on a specific value in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How to join or group an array. For example:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => data0
 1 => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => data1
```

How do i make the array above to this array below?

```
array (size=1)
 0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => data0
      1 => data1
```

Is this possible to join 2 values in 1 index? please help.

Comment: Show some coding effort?

Comment: Yes it is possible, though my guess is that the data structure you are showing as your desired data structure may still not be ideal depending on  how you are going to try to look up data in it.  You should show your coding efforts to this point, explicitly explain where you are running into trouble, and also talk about your data access pattern so you can get advice on best data structure.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh question edited.. can you help me with this?.. thanks..

Comment: @MikeBrant thanks for the response.. question edited..

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
$array1 = array(
    array (
       'month' =>  'January',
       'item1' =>  '120000'
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'February' ,
      'item1' =>  '1' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'March' ,
      'item1' =>  '5206' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'April', 
      'item1' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'May' ,
      'item1' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'June',
      'item1' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'January' ,
      'item2' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'February' ,
      'item2' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'March' ,
      'item2' =>  '5106' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'April', 
      'item2' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'May', 
      'item2' =>  '0' 
    ),
    array (
      'month' =>  'June', 
      'item2' =>  '0' 
    )
);

$resp = call_user_func(function($array1,$keyval){
    $response = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($array1 as $arr1){
        array_walk($array1, function($item,$index)use($arr1,&$response,$count,$keyval){
            if($arr1[$keyval] == $item[$keyval]){
                $response[$count] = array_merge($arr1,$item);
            }
        });
        $count++;
    }
    foreach($response as $key=>$value){
        $c = 1;
        array_walk($response,function($item,$index)use($value,&$c,&$response,$key,$keyval){
            if($item[$keyval] == $value[$keyval]){
                if($c > 1){
                    unset($response[$index]);
                }
                $c++;
            }
        });
    }
    return $response;
},$array1,'month');
var_dump($resp);
```